# How to add worker role to virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have the following scenario on Azure:

1 Virtual Network

2 Virtual Machines (in the virtual network)

1 Worker Role

Im trying to add the worker role to the virtual network unsuccessfully.

What I am trying to do: The worker role need to access the virtual machines via PSRemoting (powershell)

The question is: How I add the worker role to the same network of my VMs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `<NetworkConfiguration>` section to the .cscfg file for your worker role.  It's not possible to add it using the portal.

Here is a link describing the schema for the configuration you need to add.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156091.aspx